# Can I keep large encrypted files in my mailbox on mail provider server?

Tags: email, privacy, file-encryption, storage

Is there any restriction or policy of large e-mail providers (such as GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail and similar) for keeping/storing large encrypted files by the users within their disk quota in 3rd party mailbox for privacy purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all mail systems have a limit on email size. You can howevr overcome it by splitting your big file in several mails.

As for policy, you should read the terms of use of each provider to figure out. For instance GMail restricts (restricted?) usage of third-party applications to avoid that you use GMail as a virtual drive (there were several programs precisely for doing that).